# How can JSON files be parse into name: value?

Tags: node.js, json, puppeteer

I generated a webpage cookie using puppeteer like the following:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "__Secure-3PSIDCC",
    "value": "sec",
    "domain": ".youtube.com",
    "path": "/",
    "expires": 1677041890.31475,
    "size": 88,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "secure": true,
    "session": false,
    "sameSite": "None",
    "sameParty": false,
    "sourceScheme": "Secure",
    "sourcePort": 443
  },
  {
    "name": "SIDCC",
    "value": "sec",
    "domain": ".youtube.com",
    "path": "/",
    "expires": 1677041890.314666,
    "size": 79,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "secure": false,
    "session": false,
    "sameParty": false,
    "sourceScheme": "Secure",
    "sourcePort": 443
  }... //and so on
```

How can I parse the json so it would be `name.value`?
What I am doing now is:

```js
const cookies = await page.cookies();
await fs.writeFile('./cookies.json', JSON.stringify(cookies, null, 2));
```

The thing is youtube does not allow cookies in file...
any solution so I can format the json to `name.value`?
The wanted output would be `The reseult shold be like this __Secure-3PSIDCC:sec; SIDCC=sec; another=value;` 
Thanks

Comment: Hi
as the json file above, there are a name and a value in each block of data.
so i would like the output of: 
__Secure-3PSIDCC:sec; SIDCC=sec; another=value;

Comment: The reseult shold be like this

__Secure-3PSIDCC:sec; SIDCC=sec; another=value;

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71229606/edit) to include that information.

Comment: Wait, is it `name:value` or `name=value`?

Comment: its name=value not name:value

Comment: I asked as you have both in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71229606/how-can-json-files-be-parse-into-name-value?noredirect=1#comment125906672_71229606)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the array in your question is the value in `cookies`, you can [*map*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array to the values you want and then [*join*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) it into the final string

```js
const cookies = [{"name":"__Secure-3PSIDCC","value":"sec","domain":".youtube.com","path":"/","expires":1677041890.31475,"size":88,"httpOnly":true,"secure":true,"session":false,"sameSite":"None","sameParty":false,"sourceScheme":"Secure","sourcePort":443},{"name":"SIDCC","value":"sec","domain":".youtube.com","path":"/","expires":1677041890.314666,"size":79,"httpOnly":false,"secure":false,"session":false,"sameParty":false,"sourceScheme":"Secure","sourcePort":443}]

const cookieString = cookies.map(({ name, value }) =>
  `${name}=${value}`).join("; ")
  
console.log("cookieString:", cookieString)
```

Comment: Oh thanks! So if i have a complete file of the cookies, can i just do const cookies = require("./myjson.json")  ?

Comment: @YueYue probably ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Let me try this